# How can I extract and store query result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

How can I extract and store query result in elastic search, I want to do this entire process in java.

Let's consider the dummy data

PUT /_bulk {"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"2"}} {"name":"abc","old_data":20,"data":0,"old_data_id":"xy"} {"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"3"}} {"name":"def","old_data":20,"data":2,"old_data_id":"xy"} {"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"4"}} {"name":"ghi","old_data":20,"data":0,"old_data_id":"yz"} {"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"4"}} {"name":"jkl","old_data":18,"data":2,"old_data_id":"xy"} {"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"4"}} {"name":"mno","old_data":18,"data":18,"old_data_id":"rt"}

I'm trying to extract and store query result.

Query I want to write in elastic search is

```
SELECT old_data_id FROM movies WHERE old_data > 0 AND data = 0
```

I had written this query,

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "old_data_id"
  ],
  "query": 
  {
    "bool": 
    {
      "must": 
      [
        {
          "match": {
            "data": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "old_data": {
              "gt": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    
  }
  }
}
```

I want to extract old_data_id from elastic search query response. How can I achieve that
how can I fit this all implementation in java or python.

Can anyone please guide me in this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to imporve the quailty of your question, btw your JSON query is just fine, do you need the Java code of it ? and which version of Elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: so basically I need to do some coding in other language also, to make connection @Amit